# Disable New User Registration Email sent to Wordpress admin email on 4.9.5

Tags: user-registration, notifications

I don't know if something changed, but I'm not able to disable the email sent to the WordPress admin mail. I tried adding this code to my theme's `functions.php` file

```
//disable default WordPress new user notification emails
if (!function_exists('wp_new_user_notification')) {
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $deprecated = null, $notify = '' ) {
        return;
    }
}
```

And tried enabling the http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-new-user-email-notifications/ plugin. But the mail keeps being sent to the admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the function [wp_new_user_notification](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/) is one of the [Pluggable Functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions). In the documention you can read:

> Pluggable functions were introduced in WordPress 1.5.1 These functions let you override certain core functions via **plugins**. The most up-to-date list of core functions that WordPress allows plugins to override is available at wp-includes/pluggable.php. WordPress loads the built-in functions only if they are undefined after all plugins have been loaded.

That means you can not override that function in your theme. Put it in an plugin and it should work.

Usefull links:

[How to override pluggable function in theme? - wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55951/how-to-override-pluggable-function-in-theme)